# How are ajax/websocket domain searching services so fast?

Tags: dns, whois

I have been using ajaxwhois for years, and there are many of these services for finding domain names now.

The fastest seem to use some sort of websocket to connect the interface to the data; but I still don't quite get how it is so lightning fast.

Simply doing a `whois whatever.com` from a shell has a noticeable delay.  Are these services really just making a bunch of direct requests (in parallel) using whois and parsing the data, or is there some other method that is escaping me?

edit:  I should be clear in that I am not confused/curious about the speediness of ajax/sockets; even assuming the server->interface delay is 0ms I don't understand how the queries themselves are being made so quickly.

edit2: links

http://ajaxwhois.com/

http://www.domainzomg.com/

Comment: Which service are you using? (url please) without this we have no idea what the speed is like or what technique they are using. Just Googled it... I take it it is this service? http://ajaxwhois.com/

Comment: After just two years, both of the OP's links are broken.  Are there any AJAX/websocket domain searching services these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the server caches the results, and probably refreshes them server-side every x hours. So all the AJAX script does, is get the cached result. You can test this by entering a common domain name like `mathematics.com`, where the search results will be very fast, and then an uncommon domain name like `howareajaxwebsocketdomainsearchingservicessofast.com` which will show a noticeable delay, the same showed by a shell command.

Comment: Woot! `howareajaxwebsocketdomainsearchingservicessofast.com` is available! you should jump on that! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do ns lookup as a part of the check. Other ways is also possible. For example many registrars has free servises that only respond if the domain is free for regitration that is mutch faster that parsing whois. If you have access to epp you could also check in the registration system.. so there is 4 ways to check. It all dep on what TLD and

Comment: First, no DNS requests are the wrong solution to the problem, because a domain can be registered but not delegated, and this is legit. As for EPP access, you need to be a registrar for that. Otherwise you can use some registrars API that will operate as a kind of proxy. PS: and you did not finish your last